# How do I manage read and write AWS Aurora host endpoints in custom MVC based PHP application?

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-rds, database-performance, amazon-aurora

I have a custom MVC based PHP application and for database I am using AWS RDS aurora mysql.
To load balance I have created a read replica of the database and I want to send read queries to read replica and write queries to writer instance of RDS database but I don't want to update anything on application level.

Is there any way to do this from AWS RDS to load balance? I want to avoid updating code as its a custom MVC framework which is a bit old code.

Comment: You can use a SQL proxy to split the read and write traffic but you risk write-and-read inconsistency due to replication lag.

Answer (score 2):

No, Your Application must update the connection string to leverage read replicas.

RDS Read Replicas – Use Cases

- You have a production database that is taking on a normal load.
- You want to run a **separate** reporting application to run some analytics on production data.
- You create a Read Replica to run the new workload there.
- You update the connection strings in your reporting application to
  make read database calls to Read Replica.
- The production application is unaffected.
- Read replicas are used for SELECT (=read) only kind of statements
  (not INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE)

Answer (score 0):

If your application results are OK with the latency of some number of milliseconds (i.e. a read might see data that is just slightly stale), here are a couple of blog posts that describe middleware to do the read-write splitting:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-to-use-proxysql-with-open-source-platforms-to-split-sql-reads-and-writes-on-amazon-aurora-clusters/

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/using-the-heimdall-proxy-to-split-reads-and-writes-for-amazon-aurora-and-amazon-rds/

Heimdall advertises that it can intelligently figure out what the lag is and account for it when deciding how to route the read queries.

(I haven't evaluated either of those proxies to reach any conclusions of my own.)